# Resolving subdomain.localhost doesn't work with docker swarm

Tags: linux, docker, dns, docker-swarm

What I want to achieve:

- docker swarm on localhost
- dockerized reverse proxy which would forward subdomain.domain to container with app
- container with app

What I have done:

- changed /etc/hosts that now looks like:

  > 127.0.0.1               localhost 
  >   127.0.0.1               subdomain.localhost
- set up traefik to forward word.beluga to specific container

What is the problem:

- can't get to container via subdomain. It works if I use port though
- curl gives different results for subdomain and port

The question:

- what is the problem? and why?
- how to debug it and find whether problem is docker or network based? (how to check whether request even got to my container)

I'll add that I have also tried to do it on docker-machine (virtualbox) but it wasn't working. So I have moved to localhost, but as you can see it didn't help a lot.

I am losing hope, so any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There’s no such thing as subdomains of localhost. By near-universal convention, localhost resolves to the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 and the IPv6 address ::1.

You can still test virtual host with docker, but you will have to use port:

`curl -H Host:sub.localhost http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Thanks. It was very useful - Using Host header from Postman to pretend the request is coming from a subdomain (tenant)

Answer (score 0):

Late to respond but I was able to achieve this using Traefik's 2.x [routers](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/) feature like so:

```
labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.<unique name>.rule=Host(`subdomain.localhost`)"
```

in docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    image: myapp:latest    
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`myapp.localhost`)"
  
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.4
      command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker    
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
        - "9000:8080"
      volumes:
        # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I think the reason, why it works, is that Treafik is intercepting everything on localhost and just then applying rules so its Traefik specific answer.